# Function for finding the nth unique minimum value in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have this matrix...

```
mat = Table[{k, 0}, {k, 0, limit}];
```

After a series of dynamic iterative operations, some of the 0 initialized entries (i.e., those of the 2nd column of mat, i.e., mat[[All, 2]]) are replaced w/ positive integers, e.g.,

```
mat = {{0,78},{1,0},{2,0},{3,11},{4,11},{5,11},...,{limit,0}}
```

I realize that there are several standard ways for retrieving the nth minimum value of mat[[All, 2]] but, since mat has so many 0s, they do not help me.

I am looking for a standard/elegant/efficient way to find the nth UNIQUE min value of mat, along w/ its associated row index, e.g., if limit = 6 & I wanted to find the 2nd min-value/index pair, executing...

```
Print[UniqueMin[mat[[All, 2]], 2]];
```

would output...

```
{4,11}
```

Bc 11 was the 2nd smallest unique value in mat & row 4 was where it 1st occurred.

Comment: Why `{4,11}`, not `{3,11`}?

Comment: @corey979 Bc Mathematica starts index @ 1, not 0. You'd be right, if I was asking for the associated row value, but I asked for the associated row index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UniqueMin[list_?VectorQ, n_Integer?Positive] :=
 Module[{min = Union[list][[n]]},
  {Position[list, min][[1, 1]], min}]

mat = {{0, 78}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 11}, {4, 11}, {5, 11}};

UniqueMin[mat[[All, 2]], 2]

(* {4, 11} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mat = {{0, 78}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 11}, {4, 11}, {5, 11}};
```

Using `TakeSmallestBy`

```
Last @ TakeSmallestBy[Union[mat] -> {"Index", "Element"}, First, 2]
```

{2, {1, 0}}

**Revision**

As Daniel Lichtblau commented the above answer is wrong. A correct answer, using his suggested `PositionSmallest`, would be:

```
{#, mat[[#, -1]]} & @ PositionSmallest[mat[[All, 2]], 2][[-1, 1]]
```

{4, 11}

Comment: The position to be found her eis actually 4 though. `In[1135]:= 
mat = {{0, 78}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 11}, {4, 11}, {5, 11}, {33, 0}};
posn = First[Last[PositionSmallest[mat[[All, 2]], 2]]]

Out[1136]= 4`

Comment: Thank you, Daniel, see revision

Answer (score 1):

```
mat = {{0, 78}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 11}, {4, 11}, {5, 11}};
```

Using `Sort` and `FirstPosition`:

```
{FirstPosition[mat, {_, #}][[1]], #} &@Sort[Union[mat[[All, 2]]]][[2]]

(*{4, 11}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would use PositionIndex followed by KeySort

The variants below differ in either accessing the parts of the result or using a pattern match (which is slightly slower)

````
(* version 1*)
Clear[UniqueMin]

UniqueMin[list_?VectorQ, n_Integer?Positive] := With[
  {entry = Take[#, {n}]& @ KeySort @ PositionIndex @ list},
  {entry[[1, 1]], Keys[entry][[1]]}]

UniqueMin[mat[[All, 2]], 2]
(* {4, 11} *)


(* version 2 *)
Clear[UniqueMin]

UniqueMin[list_?VectorQ, n_Integer?Positive] := 
 With[{entry = Take[#, {n}]& @ KeySort @ PositionIndex @ list}, 
  Replace[entry, Association[Rule[x_, List[y_, ___]]] :> {y, x}]]

UniqueMin[mat[[All, 2]], 2]
(* {4, 11} *)

```
````